# Is possible share data between In-house app and AppStore distribute app use Shared Keychain Access?

Tags: ios

I will create two app. There are In-house app and AppStore distribute app.
I want to share data between them. 
I will use Shared Keychain Access or App Group Functionality. (not other way)
But they must be the same app id prefix.
I know i need create two team for in-house app and AppStore distribute App.

Can someone give me advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  As you noted in your question, for shared keychain to work, apps must share an App ID prefix.  The App ID prefix is unique and assigned by Apple to your developer team.

Since you will have two independent teams for your apps, they cannot share a keychain.